# Windows OpenFileDialog with more than one file type

Tags: windows, filenames, openfiledialog

I want to open a Windows OpenFileDialog with two possible selections:

```
foo*bar.xml
*.xml
```

The file name wildcard is specified with the FileName property but it applies to every file selection specified with the Filter property.

With the Filter property, users can select more than one set of file *types*, but is there a way to specify different file *names* in one dialog?

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The file name wildcard is specified with the FileName property

That doesn't work, only the Filter property can be used to filter files.  Furthermore, a wildcard like `foo*bar.xml` does do what you hope it does, anything past the * is ignored.  A wildcard doesn't behave like a regular expression at all.  This goes way, way back to early operating systems that didn't have the horsepower to implement regex.  Definitely at CP/M, probably as far back as RSX.

Options are very limited, you can specify multiple wildcards by separating them with a ; semicolon.  Like `"Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|All files (*.*)|*.*"`.  But that's as far as you can push it.